# Question about ETL Work on Python/in General

Tags: python, sql, csv, etl

Right now I have a challenge where I have to upload a CSV file into SQL but before I have to check if data is ok, and other stuff with Python. But watching by my own hand there are some rows that are wrong, so...

***QUESTION*:**

How do you deal with, again, "wrong rows", but also well written and respecting the syntax of the SQL table? See this for example:

This is the CSV:

```
Jonathan; (empty, but is valid)
Nancy; She is a student in the MIT
Juan; Juan is a software developer in –
"Oracle since five years ago""; (also empty and valid, and yes it does have two "" at the end)
Gisselle; she works in Microsoft since last year etc...
```

And this is how it is persisted:

```
id (auto generated)   name (varchar, not null)             description (optional)
1                     Juan                                 Juan is a software developer in
2                     Oracle since five years ago          null
```

See? That part of the "Oracle since five years ago" is a continuation of Juan description which for some reason was in another row, but this technically for SQL is okay, but, as you can imagine, is not useful and totally wrong.

In this type of cases, you have to delete (or fix) the row by you own hand (or writing an specific code for that specific CSV)? There isn't any test or something than you can write in code for at least detect this issues or similar? And not only for Python, but with any other tool where you can do ETL work?

Comment: You will have to come up with rules that help you decide where a field starts and ends. Sure, a person that knows English and understands the meaning of the text can deduce that those two parts probably go together, but there's no amount of Python you can write that would be able to do the same. What other rules can you think of that would tell you how to know where this record stops and starts?

Comment: Also, what column would that dangling `null` value correspond to?

Comment: mmm, perhaps the ammount of words? wich also can be ignored, for example if it was only written "Oracle" in the name of the second row.

Comment: to none Grismar, for some reason (probably as part of the challenge) there is a row in this CSV like that, it didn't "push" any value to disorder the tables, if thats what you thought

Comment: Since we don't have access to the source file (you didn't provide the .csv, nor any code that you possibly wrote to generate the above), it's not easy to help here. But, for example, it's possible that in the source file, fields are separated by tab characters, or some other special character. If you share an example of the actual source data, it'd be a lot easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: this is from the CSV:
Jonathan; (empty, but is valid)
Nancy; She is a student in the MIT
Juan; Juan is a software developer in –
"Oracle since five years ago""; (also empty and valid)
Gisselle; she works in Microsoft since last year
etc...

Comment: You would do well to include a few lines of the data in the question, in a code block - apparently user @o.jones has taken a stab at what is likely in your data, but obviously the answer would be of more use to yourself and others if you provided a good example

Comment: i already put some raw lines from the csv there

Comment: If there's a `;` after `years ago""` but not after `in the MIT`, it appears someone has already processed the original data and made a complete mess of it. At that point, trying to systematically process it gets hard, if not impossible. I wonder if there really was one though, because you didn't share a fragment of the original data - instead you edited it and added comments to it, so it's all rather pointless. You would do well to share some of the original data - without edits or comments.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, check and check again that your software is reading your .csv file correctly.

It is **really** easy to misread CSV files; they have all sorts of variant formats.

In your example I guess the string `Juan is a software developer in Oracle since five years ago` has, in your CSV file, a newline between `in` and `Oracle`. And, I guess that whole string is enclosed in `"` quotes.

The thing about CSV `"` quotes and newlines is this: A newline that appears within a quoted string is *not* the end of the CSV record. Rather it is part of that string.

Use a fully debugged CSV parsing package. Writing this code yourself will make you suffer. Don't try to reinvent this wheel. You will, instead, invent another flat tire. Seriously. Ask me how I know this sometime.

Here's how to track this down.

- Load it into MS Excel, Libre Office Calc, or some other spreadsheet program and cast your eyeballs upon it.
- Then cast your eyeballs upon the Python data that results from reading it into your program.
- Are the rows and columns split up the same way in your program and the spreadsheet?
- If not, you must get to the bottom of that problem.

If you use a good CSV reading package, its documentation will tell you how to configure it to use "Excel-compatible options." Do that. And I think your question will be answered.

For what it's worth the various database client programs usually offer "Import from CSV" tools. They will get this right, and you may not need a Python program at all.

Comment: thanks for the info! I already updated the question to show how a part of the CSV looks like, in this case is separated by  ; and the enter starts a new row and only the "Oracle since five years ago" has this "", and it end with two, but that seems to do nothing

Comment: It's possible your file was created with format errors. Ask the person who provided it to you, perhaps? If ti's just one line that's broken, fix it with a text editor.